# Show location on maps in jsp website using javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to accept latitude and longitude from user and display it using javascript. I am using this code.

```
      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"                 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
             <html>
              <head>
                     <title>Localizing the Map</title>
                    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

                    <link href="/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
                    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&language=ja"></script>
                  <script>


     function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
         zoom: 8,
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);
       }

       google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="map-canvas"></div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

The page is loaded but doesnt show anything. Does it needs any javascript plugins. I googled but got only IDE to develop JavaScript projects. What if I want to use my existing IDE(ecllipse Juno).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the CSS. Add:

```
<style>
    html, body, #map-canvas {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

As per Google's example and it will work. Tested locally.

Comment: how to use it. I dont have any isea of css

Comment: Um, it's directly from the Google example you took your original code from, you just missed the CSS. View the source of the page: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/map-simple

Comment: thanks it worked. I am accepting your answer. Does it create any canvas?

Comment: I don't think so - inspect the element to find out